# How to hide value from Firebase in multi part request iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase in my iOS app but I want to ensure a value is never sent from the server to the client.

Users in the app are shown to each other based on a score they have. So a user with a score of 5 will see other users who have a score of 5. I don't want to include this value in the request/response to Firebase.

Where I can manage the server I can have server side logic handle this by looking up the user on the server then calling a function that determines who has the same score and returning the relevant users without the client ever receiving the user score.

With Firebase my understanding is I'd have to send the value to Firebase in a query i.e. get all users with this user's score.

How can I do this without exposing the user's score? I want something along the lines of a node `user_scores` where I can query the current users score and then using this query another node `users` to return me the relevant users without having to nest the query on the client and thus expose the score in the request/response?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is pretty much on point, there is no way to make a "dynamic" query like this without actually exposing the varying parameter to the client.

Here are two ideas you could try to use as a workaround:

1. A variation of *"security by obscurity"*: instead of exposing a single number, obfuscate that value in a way that makes guessing its purpose and other values an unpleasant experience; and share that with the client.
   If you keep your users **grouped by** this key, not just as a flat list where this is a child node, you can use security rules to enforce that the user cannot read any other group than theirs.
   *(Note that this is also true for numerical values. Security rules are not filters.)*
2. In a much more involved strategy, you could make the query **static**. Store and maintain a list of matching users per user, so the clients can load their own personal list without any varying parameters sans the UID.
   *(This is probably not really feasible if there is a lot of movement involved. But it might work in some edge cases.)*